# Could not resolve...............files for configuration

Tags: android

When I run my project , I face this error . How can I solve it??Please help me

---

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform annotation-jvm-1.7.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download annotation-jvm-1.7.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.7.0): No cached version available for offline mode

| header 1 |
| --- |
| cell 1 |

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 |

Here is my dependency